# How do I get duration of track using MediaPlayer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, audio, xamarin

I would like to find the duration of an audio track using Xamarin C# Android. I am using MediaPlayer to play my audio files.

Most other answers on SO and the official documentation point me to a simple method MediaPlayer.GetDuration() in the [MediaPlayer class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.MediaPlayer/)

However, intellisense is not bringing this up as an option. Get Track Info appears which might be useful though?

[image: where is get duration?]

Full code below

```
public void StartAudio()
{
    if (player == null)
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Completion += PlayNextTrack;              
    }
    else
    {
        player.Reset();
    }

    player.Looping = false;
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = Assets.OpenFd(currentTrack.FileName.ToString());
    player.SetDataSource(descriptor.FileDescriptor,descriptor.StartOffset,descriptor.Length);         
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();

    if (currentTrack.TrackType == TrackType.Pause)
    {
        int timerLength = 0;
        int duration = player.GetDuration();
        timerLength = duration - 10; // or something...
        StartAlarmClockTimer(timerLength); // Special Case. Attach a countdown timer to this track
    }
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Playing Track " + currentTrack.TrackNumber.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();               
}
```

Comment: Damnit. Thanks. Why wouldn't something so simple be in the documentation? Is this normal?

Comment: Thank you. Do you know (out of curiousity) why getDuration doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm using standard Xamarin C#.  I'm confused. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin typically renames Java style Get methods as standard C# Properties

So `GetDuration()` in Java becomes `Duration` in C#